# Random number generator with user input code doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, random

another beginner question from me. I apologize in advance, but could you please help me out here? So I want to create this random number generator which will generate numbers 1-100 and ask for user input. The user ought to guess until (s)he finally gets the right number. At the end, the program should print "you guessed from xx attempt". So the problem is, when I tested the code, twice it ran correctly, and other 2 times it was wrong (the number of attempts was shown wrong). Now also I feel the code could be written in a much better way, but don't know exactly how.Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class JavaApplication2018 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number, please");
        int attempt = input.nextInt();
        Random dice = new Random();
        int number;
        number = dice.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int counter = 0;
       while (number > attempt) 
       {
           System.out.println("I imagined a bigger number. Guess again!");
           attempt = input.nextInt();
           counter++;
       }

       while (number < attempt)
       {
           System.out.println("I imagined a smaller number. Guess again!");
           attempt = input.nextInt();
           counter++;
       }

       if (number == attempt)
       {

           counter++;
       }


       System.out.println("You guessed from " + counter +". attempt" );

    }  


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user guess once, if it is bigger than the random number, then it will iterate once more, if not, it will iterate at the second while, and if the guess is again bigger that the attempt, it will be no good and the code will end without the result you wanted.

```
while (number > attempt || number<attempt) 
       {
        if(number>attempt){
           System.out.println("I imagined a bigger number. Guess again!");}             
        else
           System.out.println("I imagined a smaller number. Guess again!");

        attempt = input.nextInt();
        counter++;
       }
if (number == attempt)
   {

       counter++;
   }


   System.out.println("You guessed from " + counter +". attempt" );

}
```

this code should be better

Comment: That's neat, thank you so much!  Your loop looks much better, and it works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Glad it worked! did you understand the logic error? cause i'll be happy to explain again if necessary

Comment: I think Iunderstand. I think I shouldn't have had two separate while loops because the computer checks the first one and if it is true, tries again, and if not then checks the other one, and then stops. Doesn't go back to the first one but stops instead. That's the error, right?

Comment: could you please help me clear something out, I've just figured I have another doubt now. In your code else statement can actually include a case where number equals attempt (since 'else' itself means any other case but the one included in the if statement, right? So basically if the number equals attempt, it will not get to the next if statement, but will end there, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, i have'nt even thought about it. Add if so it'll be else if(number<attempt). Really nice job

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you don't need two `while`. you can put it all together in one `while` and put an `if` in it like that:

```
while(number ! attempt){
if(number > attempt)
...
else
...
}
System.out.println("good gusse" );
```

second, I need more details about the error before I will be able to help you fix it

Comment: so twice, I got the right number of attempts I made, and the other two times I checked the code, it showed wrong number of the attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The user introduces the first input, then it enters an infinite loop in which the user will be asked for numbers until the value is finally guessed. This code checks for the values introduced by the user only 2 times maximun. Select as answer if it'd helped :D

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number, please");
    int attempt = input.nextInt();
    int number;
    number = new Random().nextInt(101);
    int counter = 1;

    while (true) {

        attempt = input.nextInt();
        counter++;


        if (number > attempt) {

            System.out.println("I imagined a bigger number. Guess again!");

        }else if (number < attempt) {

            System.out.println("I imagined a smaller number. Guess again!");

        }else {

            System.out.println("You guessed from " + counter + ". attempt");
            break;

        }


    }

}
```